# How to evaluate$\int_{e}^{e^2} \frac{\ln(x)+1}{x\cdot \ln(x)}\,\mathrm dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> $$\int_{e}^{e^2} \frac{\ln(x)+1}{x\cdot \ln(x)}\,\mathrm dx$$

Im supposed to use u-substitution. Now $(x\cdot \ln(x))' = \ln(x) + 1$ therefore
u (or the inner function) $= x\cdot \ln(x)$ and $du = \ln(x)+1$.

$\int_{e}^{e^2} \frac{\ln(x)+1}{x\cdot \ln(x)}\,\mathrm dx = \int_{e}^{e^2}{u^{-1}du}$

Now when I try to find the function that derived is $\frac{\ln(x)+1}{x\cdot \ln(x)}$, I get into a problem:

$F(x) = \frac{1}{0}u^{0}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put $u=x\ln (x) $ you forgot to change the limits they should become $e,2e^2$ thus answer should be $\ln (u)|_{e}  ^{2e^2}=ln (2e^2)-ln (e)=\ln (2e ) $

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\ln(x\cdot \ln(x))|^{e^2}_e = \ln(e^2\cdot ln(e^2))-\ln(e \cdot \ln(e)) = \ln(2e^2)-\ln(e) = 1+\ln(2)$ ?

Comment: $ln(2e) = ln(2) + 1$

Answer (score 2):

we have,$$(\ln(|x\ln x |))'= \frac{\ln(x)+1}{x\cdot \ln(x)}$$
Hence

$$\color{blue}{\int_{e}^{e^2} \frac{\ln(x)+1}{x\cdot \ln(x)}\,\mathrm dx = \left[\ln(x\ln x )\right]_e^{e^2}, = \ln 2 +1}$$

**OR you may see that,** 
$$\int_{e}^{e^2} \frac{\ln(x)+1}{x\cdot \ln(x)}\,\mathrm dx = \int_{e}^{e^2} \frac{\mathrm d(x\cdot\ln(x))}{x\cdot \ln(x)}\,$$
Setting $u= x\ln x$ yiedls
$$\int_{e}^{e^2} \frac{\ln(x)+1}{x\cdot \ln(x)}\,\mathrm dx = \int_{e}^{e^2} \frac{\mathrm d(x\cdot\ln(x))}{x\cdot \ln(x)}\,=  \int_{e}^{2e^2} \frac{\mathrm d u}{u}\,= \ln (2e^2)-\ln e=\ln 2+1$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: Let $u = \ln x$. Can you finish it?

Answer (score 0):

Doing $x=e^u$ and $\mathrm dx=e^u\,\mathrm du$, you get$$\int_1^2\frac{u+1}u\,\mathrm du=\int_1^21+\frac1u\,\mathrm du.$$Can you take it from here?